# How to find the selected option of a Dropdown?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How do we find the selected option of a Dropdown in Selenium Webdriver??

I tried -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator1));
Select select = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> SO = select.getAllSelectedOptions();
String S = SO.toString();
System.out.println(S);
```

which returns WebElements like -

```
[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (c388e8a8-09d5-41b9-b086-0278c639d8b1)] -> xpath: .//*[@id='city']]] -> tag name: option]]
```

I want to find the option that is selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `getFirstSelectedOption()` method on your `Select` object to resolve the selected element and you can get it's text by the `getText()`method. See example below:

**For single selection:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator1));
Select select = new Select(element);
WebElement selectedOption = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
System.out.println(selectedOption.getText());
```

**For multiple selection:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator1));
Select select = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> selectedOptions = select.getAllSelectedOptions();
for(WebElement selectedOption : selectedOptions) {
    System.out.println(selectedOption.getText());
}
```

Comment: Beautiful!! Can we modify this to get all selected elements?? Like from a list where we can select more than one element?