# How can I display text of an option that has a certain attribute?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a dropdown with multiple options.

```
<select id="ctl00_cphMainContent_dq16_response" name="ctl00$cphMainContent$dq16$response">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
  <option value="282">Technology Architecture</option>
  <option value="281">The Avengers</option>
  <option value="280">Human Resources</option>
  <option value="279">R&D</option>
  <option value="278">Quality Services</option>
  <option value="277">Publishing</option>
  <option value="275">Product Development</option>
  <option value="284">MI6 - British Secret Service</option>
  <option value="285">Finance</option>
  <option value="276">Public Relations</option>
  <option value="283">Client Services</option>
</select>
```

For my automated tests, I have a class where I create objects. So for all my dropdowns, I have an object created. Here is the object I created for the above dropdown.

```
public static final String Basic7_Dropdown = "css=select#ctl00_cphMainContent_dq16_response";
```

I use this object in other methods to test the dropdown. For example, I have a method where I want to verify all the available options in the dropdown.

```
protected void verifyDropDownValues(String selector, String expectedvalue) {
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
listA.add(expectedvalue);
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Element> options = driver.getElements(selector);
    for(Element opt : options){
    String actualtext = opt.getText();
    listB.add(actualtext);
}
Assert.assertEquals(listB, listA);
}
```

When I use this method in my tests, the selector parameter is the Basic7_Dropdown object that I created.

```
verifyDropDownValues(AppObjects.Basic7_Dropdown, "Please Select...\nTechnology Architecture\nThe Avengers\nHuman Resources\nR&D\nQuality Services\nPublishing\nProduct Development\nMI6 - British Secret Service\nFinance\nPublic Relations\nClient Services");
```

By using the same Basic7_Dropdown object I created, how can I create a method that will find the option that has the attribute of selected="selected", and then display that text.

I tried the below code hoping to get it to return the selected value of "Please Select...". However, it doesn't return any options.

```
List<Element> options = driver.getElements(AppObjects.Basic1_Dropdown);
    for(Element opt : options){
        if (opt.getAttribute("selected") != null) {
          String actualtext = opt.getText();
          System.out.println(actualtext);
        }
    }
```

I don't believe my list is getting all the options. When I run the below code, it only prints "null".

```
List<Element> options6 = driver.getElements(AppObjects.Basic1_Dropdown);
    for(Element opt : options6){
        System.out.println(opt.getAttribute("selected"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS to simply find the `<option>` and return the text.

```
String textValue = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id^='ct100'][id$='response'] option[selected='selected']")).getText();
// textValue = "Please Select..." now
```

Also, if you are new to selenium using java, could I interest you in the [Getting Started with Selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) framework.  It's a proven framework that I've used and incorporated into enterprise systems.

To print the text of all the elements that have that `selected` attribute.. do:

```
for (WebElement option : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select[id^='ct100'][id$='response'] option[selected='selected']")))
    System.out.println(option.getText());
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Is there a way to do this without adding option[selected='selected'] to the CSS? I am wanting to create a method that I can reuse for all dropdowns. I would have the css of the dropdown as a parameter, and then the expected text of the option that has selected='selected' as another parameter. If the expected text matches the actual text, then it passes.

Comment: the trick here is to fetch the ATTRIBUTE.  With CSS you can find attributes by specifying `element[ATTRIBUTE='attributevalue']` in our case, we are looking for an option with the attribute `selected`.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain this information without using 'option[selected='selected'] as part of the CSS? My goal is to create a method that I can reuse with all the dropdowns. So when I find the element, I would only use the CSS of select#ctl00_cphMainContent_dq16_response, or the CSS of any of the dropdowns I want to find. It would then look through all the dropdown options, and then return the text of those that have an attribute of selected='selected'. 

Does that make sense, or will above example do this, and I am just over complicating things.

Comment: sounds like you may be over-complicating things.  If you need to select using a different dropdown, then just change `select[id^='ct100'][id$='response']` to whatever selector finds your dropdown.

Comment: Thank you. I know that changing the CSS to the new dropdown value will work. However, there is a reason that I want to us the CSS without option[selected='selected']". I have edited my original question to better explain this. Hopefully I included enough information.

Comment: just do a simple: `if (opt.getAttribute("selected") != null)` in your `for` loop..

Comment: I tried adding if (opt.getAttribute("selected") != null) in my for loop. However, it doesn't return any options. I was hoping it would return the selected option, which is "Please Select...". I've edited my question to show the code I am using. Hopefully its just something small that I am overlooking.

Comment: I was able to get this to work. I found this solution helpful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006192](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621075/how-to-find-the-selected-option-of-a-dropdown?rq=1)